# UITextField is not clearing when pressing button

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to clear my `UITextField` on button click but when I press the button it doesn't clear. Here is my code:

```
self.textfiled = @"";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
self.textfiled.text=@"";
```

instead of

```
self.textfiled=@"";
```